# Variation output hall effect sensor

Tags: sensor, analog, hall-effect

I'm using the hall effect sensor *A1301EUA-T*, I'm feeding it with 5V. At the *VOUT* output when there is no magnetic field there is 2.5V. When approaching the NORTH POLE of the magnet *VOUT* ranges from 2.5 up to 5v. When it approaches the SOUTH POLE of the *VOUT* magnet it varies from 2.5 up to 0v. To have a variation in *VOUT* from 0v to 5v I need 2 magnets, move one away and bring the other closer. My question is: how do I have a variation in *VOUT* from 0v to 5v approaching just one magnet, that is, I want it when I have no magnetic field close to the sensor I have 0v in *VOUT*?

Here is my circuit:[image: circuit]

Answer (score 2):

Subtract 2.5 volts and apply a gain factor of two. This can be done quite easily with an opamp but it's likely you'll need a negative supply to reach precisely 0 volts and a positive supply greater than 5 volts to reach an output of 5 volts.

Comment: @Trevor: That's "*bear* in mind". The mis-spelling usually appears on this site as "*bare with me*" which reads as an invitation to undress together. Definition: **bear** bɛː *verb*, support; carry the weight of. I know you'll care!

Comment: @Transistor sigh.. thanks I have always had an issue with homophones, and too lazy to go check for this...

Comment: +1. I'd add, "bear in mind, you will be more susceptible to stray magnetic fields with this mechanical/magnetic arrangement."

Comment: Now that's betterer by myles.